# Primes of form $n^{n+1} - (n+1)^n$

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers

I was playing with some numbers today and saw (with a bit of joy) that $3^4 - 4^3$ is the $(3 + 4)$th prime number, which is sort of neat. Then naturally I asked the question, what kind of number $n$ would make $n^{n+1} - (n+1)^n$ a prime number?

A quick computer calculation showed that for $n < 1000$, we have 3, 6, 9, 12, 44, and 883. (There is, of course, [an OEIS sequence](http://oeis.org/A072179) for it, which includes one more term 1277). It seems kind of natural to me, then, to guess that there are infinitely many such numbers. But is this the case? Has this been proven or disproven?

My intuition is that this is yet another one of those problems that have simple description but convoluted nature. Nevertheless, I decided to ask here to see if there's a surprisingly simple answer that I just missed. Any ideas or reference to related literature would be much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Oh, that was just a pure guess...I should be more clear about it, sorry.

Comment: This would make an amusing sequence problem: What is the next term in the sequence 3, 6, 9, 12, 44, and 883?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Asymptotically, $f_n = n^{n+1} - (n+1)^n \sim n^{n+1}$ as $n \to \infty$, so heuristically the probability that $f_n$ is prime should be on the order of 
$\dfrac{1}{\log(f_n)} \approx \dfrac{1}{n \log n}$.  Now $\sum_{n=2}^\infty \dfrac{1}{n \log n}$ diverges to $+\infty$, so we might indeed expect infinitely many primes in this
sequence.  However, this divergence is so slow that we may never know more than a few more of those primes.   The "expected" number of primes $f_n$ from $n=1278$ to $n=M$ would
be approximately $\log \log M - \log \log 1277$, which is $1$ for $M = e^{e \log(1277)} \approx 2.78 \times 10^8$.  $f_M$ would then be a number with about $2.34 \times 10^9$ digits... a bit big for my computer.

Comment: Good observation there! Interesting enough, though, Alexander Adamchuk reported on the OEIS page that the next number is 6279, which is quite small compared to your estimation. I'm still running primality test on that number, which is going to take a while...

Comment: $f_n$ is never divisible by $2$ or $3$ or $5$, so that ups the primality probability a little.

Comment: $f_n$ is divisible by $3$ if $n \equiv 4 \mod 6$, I think.

Comment: And $f_n$ is divisible by $5$ for $n \equiv 13$ or $16 \mod 20$.

Comment: More generally, for any prime $p$, $f_n \mod p$ is periodic with period $p(p-1)$.  It appears to me (from looking at the first $100$ primes) like the probability of $f_n \equiv 0 \mod p$ is typically not too far from $1/p$.

Comment: The reported number is **6279**. The computation took way too long on my computer that I had to stop it for other things...

Comment: OK, I can report that $6279^{6280} - 6280^{6279}$ passes the Fermat primality test for bases $2$, $3$ and $5$.

Comment: Maple has now confirmed that this is (very probably) prime.  This uses one strong pseudo-primality test and one Lucas test.